# regex help: Replacing characters

Tags: regex, sed

I want to change characters in a json file. I tried some commands but didn't find a solution.

Input:

```json
{
      "cpu" : 0.0789131391278358,
      "disk" : 0,
      "diskread" : 18524238336,
      "diskwrite" : 26161936516096,
}
```

Output:

```json
{
      "{#cpu}" : 0.0789131391278358,
      "{#disk}" : 0,
      "{#diskread}" : 18524238336,
      "{#diskwrite}" : 26161936516096,
}
```

How is the correct regex command for sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/\"\(\w\+\)\" :/"{#\1}" :/g'
```

Comment: `sed -re 's/"(\w+)" :/"{#\1}" :/g'` - easier to read, same result.